# installing Dash in Ubuntu-MATE

Tags: unity, desktop-environments, ubuntu-mate

How can I install Unity components like DASH in Ubuntu-MATE desktop environment? I've tried searching the Web for this but didn't find any solution whether it is possible to install DASH package separately and use it in Mate which does not uses Unity,Though I can use Control-Center in MATE.

Comment: Why not just use Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you will be interested in [Mutiny](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/02/ubuntu-mate-16-04-unity-style-desktop).

It is a Unity-style layout for the MATE in Ubuntu MATE 16.04.